# How do the threat mechanics work in TERA?

Tags: tera

I'm used to the somewhat more normal "accumulative" threat in other MMOs, where if there aren't any "1 shot" mechanics, the tank can generally AFK after the first minute or so.

EnMasse's TERA seems to work very differently. On my priest, I find myself pulling aggro constantly, even late in the fight. From a Lancer's perspective as well, it seems like they need to stay exposed most of the time (and take a good deal damage) or hit the AoE taunt on CD.

It's fairly obvious that this threat mechanism isn't accumulative, but are there any hard rules for how it works?

Comment: I do know some bosses like to switch it up, it has been a while so i can't remember which. But they just keep resetting the agro.

Comment: "How do threats work" implies that there are multiple things called "threat" that I'm asking about. I'm not asking about taunts, I'm asking about the threat system... reverting.

Comment: Yes and i'm saying it has been a while, and that bosses just switch around. The "threat" is on the tank when he taunts, and mostly what i have noticed is when the boss does a special move(jumps in the air, does a slam) the "threat" resets. Making the tank having to do taunt to recapture the "threat".

Comment: @Lyrion: Sorry, my comment wasn't really directed at you. Someone had changed the title of my question to be... not entirely accurate. I was reverting that change and explaining my reversion.

Comment: @McGreen Ah sorry I figured it was directed at me, since i was talking about agro. Anyway, the fun part about Tera is even if you pull agro just move away. You can dodge/block most attacks and thats the fun part about it.

Answer (score 1):

It **looks like** the monster has a limitied "memory" of last players' actions (size unknown). Most recent action removes the oldest one from the memory.

Some actions generate a lot of threat: taunts, massive damage, especially criticals, heals. If the player's threat accumulated from most recent actions is bigger than any other player's in the group, he gets aggro. That's why tank needs to constantly generate new threat. And that's why all you need to do to lose aggro is to run away for a while and let others generate even a little threat and push out your actions from the monster's memory. The more attacks hit monster in a meanwhile, the faster aggro will get back to the tank. This is the reason for supporters to use the regular attacks between threat-generating heals.

Comment: I can confirm this. Some folks think the actions list is somewhere between 6 and 12 actions long. An example would be if you have 5 people in a party and each of them hit twice for the same damage, then each of them would have 20% of the aggro. If one of those is a healer and cast a healing spell instead of attacking it would generate more threat. Furthermore if yet another one was a tank and used a skill that generates extra threat(challenging shout, etc)  it gets a bigger piece of the pie. Lancer's infuriate guarantees that you get aggro for that round of skills.